# Ionic + Anugular XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: php, angularjs, header, ionic

Имею мобильное приложение с Ionic + Angular. При POST запросе даёт error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ilocalleadsapp.com/api/v1/account/login?email=435345345&password=345345345345. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

Сам сервис:

```
angular.module('api.services', [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }])
    .factory('Login', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://ilocalleadsapp.com/api/v1/account/login', {email: '@email', password: '@password'}, {
        auth: {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Accept':'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization':'Bearer kek', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        }
    });
});
```

В index.php у API заголовки:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Как исправить?

В программе POSTMAN всё отлично работает.

Comment: http ответ с кодом 401 означает, что для обращения к ресурсу нужна аутентификация. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#401

Comment: У вас в запросе нет зголовка WWW-Authenticate

Comment: Не подскажите куда вставлять?